# How can I decrease the length of this code using loops?

Tags: c++

I want to use a `for` loop in this code. How can I do that?

I want to get the first and 2nd element of a string and save it in `hrs[0]`, and then get the 3rd and 4th element of the string and save it in `hrs[1]`, and so on.

```
int alarm_hrs(void){
    unsigned int hrs[6];
    char str[15],Temp1,Temp2;
    scanf(str);
    //alarm1 hrs
    Temp1 = str[0]-48;
    Temp2 = str[1]-48;
    hrs[0] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
    //alarm2 hrs
    Temp1 = str[2]-48;
    Temp2 = str[3]-48;
    hrs[1] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
    //alarm3 hrs
    Temp1 = str[4]-48;
    Temp2 = str[5]-48;
    hrs[2] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
    //alarm4 hrs
    Temp1 = str[6]-48;
    Temp2 = str[7]-48;
    hrs[3] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
    //alarm5 hrs
    Temp1 = str[8]-48;
    Temp2 = str[9]-48;
    hrs[4] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
    //alarm6 hrs
    Temp1 = str[10]-48;
    Temp2 = str[11]-48;
    hrs[5] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
    return hrs;
}
```

Comment: Well, do you see any patterns in those number literals of indexes, and constants which won't change at every step within a counting for loop for example??

Comment: Have you written loops before?  Have you tried writing a loop here?  Can you see logic being repeated?  How far did you get?  Please show your effort.

Comment: Well, you cannot rely on `size_t i = 0; for(auto& h : hrs) { h = (str[i++] - 48) * 10 + (str[i++] - 48); }` to work...

Comment: Why are you subtracting 48?  What's so special about 48?  Are you trying something like this: `Temp1 = str[4] - '0';`?

Comment: See also [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)

Answer (score 2):

You have six elements in your `hrs` array. So a loop from 0 upto 6 seems reasonable. Each time round the loop you assign to hrs. I.e

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
   ...
   hrs[i] = Temp1*10 + Temp2;
}
```

I'm sure you figured that part out for yourself.

Now the `str` array. I'm going to show the lines you wrote with the corresponding value of `i`

```
// when i equals 0
Temp1 = str[0]-48;
Temp2 = str[1]-48;

// when i equals 1
Temp1 = str[2]-48;
Temp2 = str[3]-48;

// when i equals 2
Temp1 = str[4]-48;
Temp2 = str[5]-48;

// when i equals 3
Temp1 = str[6]-48;
Temp2 = str[7]-48;

// when i equals 4
Temp1 = str[8]-48;
Temp2 = str[9]-48;

// when i equals 5
Temp1 = str[10]-48;
Temp2 = str[11]-48;
```

Now can you figure two formulae that get you from the value of `i` to indexes of `str` that you need? Just put those two lines of code into your for loop with those formulae and you're done.